# Reading a file, getting the current position and reading backwards

Tags: java, file

I'm using the BufferedReader class to search an occurrence in a large file by reading it line by line.

How can I get the current position when the occurrence is found ?
Then, how can I read in reverse the file starting at that position ?

I really searched on the net for a consistent solution but haven't found.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add some code? Check  this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write and ask a good question.

Comment: @Yaroslav : I believe that the question is clear enough : I don't know how to read a file backwards.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, and that is what you are looking for. I pointed out a link, and I'm repeating now [How to ask a smart question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25128/192104). Is a coding question, so is spected that you have tried something, doesn't matter if it is wrong, at least it shows some effort other than "I searched a lot for the code". You are a programmer and you are supposed to solve a problem. Yes, here you can search for help, but not for full solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("sample.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line = "";

    ArrayList<String> linee = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals("bb"))
            break;
        linee.add(line);

    }

    reader.close();
    for (int i = linee.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.println(linee.get(i));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think that this solution won't has performance issues as I'm dealing with 2Gb files ?

Comment: And once again, you have a useful answer, is up to you to test it and see if it answer your problem. If not, then try to come up with a new code based on this one. And if you are still stuck after several tries, then open a new question, add your code, explain what you have tried and then for sure you will have more answers.